# Problems upgrading to EF 6.1

Tags: frameworks, entity, driver, upgrade

Tried to update my EF package from nuGet, but I don't think it's installing correctly.

The installer seemed to go without a hitch, but after deleting my old .Edmx model, it will not let me add a 6.x model, as that option is greyed out with the error message "Your project references an older version of EF. To use the latest version exit this wizard and upgrade before performing this action."

Research indicated that I needed to delete the System.Data.Entity reference, but that didn't fix it. The problem seems to be that my EntityFramework.dll reference is still on 5.0 (runtime version v4.0.30319), even after the upgrade. I tried uninstalling & reinstalling EF and it still puts in the old driver under references. When I remove that EntityFramework reference, I'm able to add an EF 6 model, however since the driver is old, several namespaces aren't available that I need, such as System.Data.Entity.Core. Am I doing something wrong or do I need to download a new EntityFramework.dll driver separately, and if so, where would I get that?

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing similar problem few days ago. Some referenced project were using EF v4.4.0.0, but EF I added to current project (through NuGet) was v6.0.0.0. The problem is, that namespaces (and some constructors) changed between versions.

You can hack it by adding

```
 <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
 </assemblyBinding>
```

But this causes that program sometimes fails...

```
Method not found: 'Void System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext, Boolean)'.
```

I think that the best solution is using same version of EF across the project. Unfortunately (as in my case), sometimes you have to downgrade to old version because some projects are widely shared across the team/company.